# How to read arrays of struct from another deployed contract?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

OK i have struct array in one already deployed smart contract on mainnet.Now i need to read that array in my contract.I have address of deployed smart contract.I am trying to use it with interface. Something like this:

```
   pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

interface IContract1{
    struct UserInfo{
   uint id ;
   string ime;
}
    function arr(uint index) external returns(UserInfo memory );
}
contract Contract2{

struct UserInfo{
   uint id ;
   string ime;
}
event UserEVENT (UserInfo UserInfo);
UserInfo [] public newarr;

function foo(address addr,uint i) external {
    IContract1(addr).arr(i);
    emit UserEVENT (IContract1(addr).arr(i));
}
}
```

This is my caller contract. Of course this is oversimplified example. When i try to put IContract1(addr).arr(i); in emit or try to return `UserInfo` in `foo` function compiler throwing me an error `TypeError: Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from struct IContract1.UserInfo memory to struct Contract2.UserInfo memory requested.`

and sc with arr

```
    pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

contract Contract1{
struct UserInfo{
   uint id ;
   string ime;
}
  
UserInfo [5] public arr;

constructor()  {
    arr[0] = UserInfo(1,"Milos");
   arr[1] = UserInfo(2,"Stefan");
   arr[2] = UserInfo(3,"Sloba");
   arr[3] = UserInfo(4,"Prci");
    arr[4] = UserInfo(5,"Dovla");
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest fix is defining the struct outside both the contract and interface, this way you write it only once and there's no collision.

This compiles for me:

```js
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

struct UserInfo{
   uint id ;
   string ime;
}

interface IContract1{    
    function arr(uint index) external returns(UserInfo memory );
}

contract Contract2{
    event UserEVENT (UserInfo UserInfo);
    UserInfo [] public newarr;

    function foo(address addr,uint i) external {
        IContract1(addr).arr(i);
        emit UserEVENT (IContract1(addr).arr(i));
    }
}
```